# Angular2 Import component based on Id

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I need to decide what component needs to be displayed based on backend response.

Eg: i get this response from backend

```
{ plugin: 
    { 
      id = 'inputfieldWidgetV12' 
    }
  data: {
     value = 'helloWorld'
  }
}
```

based on this I need to display a component inputfieldWidgetV12.ts, and pass the data to its constructor : {value = 'helloWorld'}.

how can I inject the component what i do not know during implementation?

I have tried require(plugin.id) but it didn't work.

Comment: Basically I would need the same:

Here there is a widgetContainer, and using DynamicComponentLoader what loads the component using a path, and adds it using loadIntoLocation()....

See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9bhXkqVonScYm7EqiF5)

the problem is, that DynamicComponentLoader is Deprecated!, and with the advised ComponentResolver i cannot resolve a component, only if I import it... but I cannot do it, cause i do not know that...